# How to grab the percentage values inside the table in python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

I have managed to figure out the iframe direct link of the url that I am trying to work and thanks to @Ram. My new snippet however have some problems.

Issue #1: Does not display the proper percentage values

Issue #2: I dont know how to grab the title text "Contract" inside the "i class="far fa-file-alt text-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Contract"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokenholders2?m=normal&a=0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3"
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

reqblockdetails = requests.get(url,header, timeout=5)
soupblockdetails = BeautifulSoup(reqblockdetails.content, 'html.parser')
rowsblockdetails = soupblockdetails.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr', limit=10)#[1:]

for row in rowsblockdetails[1:]:
    rank = row.find_all('td')[0].text[0:].strip()
    address = row.find_all('td')[1].text[0:].strip()
    amount = row.find_all('td')[2].text[0:].strip()
    percentage = row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:]
  
    print (" {:<3} {:<25}  {:>15} {:>10} ".format(rank, address, amount, percentage))
```

Current Output: # the last column displaying 0.0000% is the problem

```
 1   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001  422,619,084,856,497.90460343   0.0000%
 2   0x8c128dba2cb66399341aa877315be1054be75da8  37,995,040,112,894.283191536   0.0000%  
 3   0xa8736b9585a01d6dcc1b6e2fc9dc208552c34b58  20,000,000,001,566.132214712   0.0000%  
 4   PancakeSwap: SAFEMOON                       14,559,745,452,918.021161369   0.0000%  
 5   0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9  14,301,351,821,601.347718476   0.0000%
```

Wanted Output: #-- Contract is from -> i class="far fa-file-alt text-secondary"

```
 1   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001  422,619,084,856,497.90460343   42.2608%  
 2   0x8c128dba2cb66399341aa877315be1054be75da8  37,995,040,112,894.283191536    3.7991%  
 3   0xa8736b9585a01d6dcc1b6e2fc9dc208552c34b58  20,000,000,001,566.132214712    2.0000%     Contract 
 4   PancakeSwap: SAFEMOON                       14,559,745,452,918.021161369    1.4684%     Contract
 5   0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9  14,301,351,821,601.347718476    1.4421%     Contract
```

Comment: From URL itself showing as `0.0000%`

Comment: I made the check now and your right. Thank you. I will edit my question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for row in rowsblockdetails[1:]:
    rank = row.find_all('td')[0].text[0:].strip()
    address = row.find_all('td')[1].text[0:].strip()
    amount = row.find_all('td')[2].text[0:].strip()
    percentage = row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:]

    try:
        cnt=row.select_one("i.far.fa-file-alt.text-secondary")['title']
    except:
        cnt=""
  
    print (" {:<3} {:<25}  {:>15} {:>10} {:<20} ".format(rank, address, amount, percentage,cnt))
```

Output:

```
 1   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001  422,620,418,588,552.378931106   0.0000%                       
 2   0x8c128dba2cb66399341aa877315be1054be75da8  37,990,958,290,743.368378822   0.0000%                       
 3   0xa8736b9585a01d6dcc1b6e2fc9dc208552c34b58  20,000,000,001,566.132214712   0.0000%  Contract 
.....
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to edit the url. Its working now with your idea and help.